# laravel how to properly esacpe inet_aton insertion?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

so for example to save user ip into db:

```
$ip = Request::getClientIp();
...
$post->user_ip = DB::raw("inet_aton('$ip')");
$post->save()
```

I don't really like this code how to properly escape the $ip variable?

Edit:
I am looking for a way of binding the variable instead of directly using him like:

```
DB::insert('insert into users (ip) values (?)', [$ip]);
```

to protect from sql injection

Comment: What don't you like about this code, what do you want to change?

Comment: @RossWilson I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#using-multiple-database-connections):

> You may also access the raw, underlying PDO instance using the getPdo
>   method on a connection instance:
>
> ```
> $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
> ```

So, in your case:

```
$ip = Request::getClientIp();
$ip = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($ip); // the escaping part

$post->user_ip = DB::raw("inet_aton($ip)");
$post->save();
```

Comment: Thanks workings I hope its the right way, a small problem with your code is I changes DB::raw("inet_aton('$ip')"); to DB::raw("inet_aton($ip)");